# AWS RDS Aurora Postgres freeable memory decreasing leads to db restart

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, memory, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a RDS Aurora Postgres instance crashing with OOM error when the freeable memory reaches close to 0. This error generates a database restart and once the freeable memory decreases again over the time, a new restart happens. After each new restart, the freeable memory goes back to around 16500MB.

Does anyone has any idea on why this is happening?

Some information:

- Number of ongoing IDLE connections: around 450 IDLE connections
- Instance class = db.r6g.2xlarge
- vCPU = 8
- RAM = 64 GB
- Engine version = 11.9

```
shared_buffers = 43926128kB
work_mem = 4MB
temp_buffers = 8MB
wal_buffers = 16MB
max_connections = 5000
maintenance_work_mem = 1042MB
autovacuum_work_mem = -1
```

These connections are keep alive for application reutilization and when new queries goes to the database, one of those connections are used by the application. This is not a pool of connection implementation, just 100 instances of my application are connected to the database.

It seems some of these connections/processes are "eating" the memory over the time. By checking the OS processes, I saw some of these processes are increasing the RES memory. For example, one idle process had 920.9 MB as RES metric but now it has 3.96 GiB.

RES metric refers to physical memory being used by the process as per this AWS doc: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.Viewing.html

I'm wondering if this issue is related to these idle connections as described here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/resources-consumed-by-idle-postgresql-connections/

Maybe I should reduce the number of connections to the database.

**Freeable Memory on CloudWatch graph:** [image]

**General metrics on CloudWatch:**
[image]

**Enhanced monitoring metrics:**
[image]

**OS processes (around 100 ongoing processes):**[image]

Comment: Get a memory dump from one of the backend processes that consumes a lot of memory - ah, wait, you are using a hosted database. Sorry, but you can only guess or ask Amazon.

Comment: 5000 is way too many allowed connections.  And 41GB is probably too much for shared_buffers as well, or at least would be if this were community PostgreSQL.

Comment: How many objects are in your database?  Every session caches metadata about every object it touches, and there is no way to expire this cache.

Comment: @jjanes these are the objects on my database: information_schema / table = 7;
public / sequence = 26;
public / table = 34;
pg_toast / index = 43;
pg_catalog / view = 59;
information_schema / view = 60;
pg_catalog / table = 62;
public / index = 79;
pg_catalog / index = 116;

Comment: As well as number of allowed connections, 450 idle connections is not small and they all can still consume memory. You should close connections as soon as you create them or try pooling them. Ultimately, this is something that should be raised with AWS support as Aurora is a managed service and there's only so much data you can obtain it from a customer POV.

Comment: The number of objects you show is not excessive.  This might be an Aurora-specific problem.